# new line, double quote giving error in json data

Tags: java, json, jsf-2, newline, double-quotes

I am creating JSON data in JSF Manually.

Below is what I am doing & is working perfectly.

### JSF Page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{MobileLogin.fetNewsData()}" />
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

### MobileLogin.java

```
public void fetNewsData() {
    try {
        ConnectToDatabase db = new ConnectToDatabase();
        Connection conn = db.makeconnection();
        PreparedStatement psmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC");
        ResultSet rs = psmt.executeQuery();

        String json = "[";
        int myTotal = 0;
        String myDate = "";
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("test 002 - " + rs.getString(1));
            if (myTotal >= 1) {
                json = json + ",";
            }
            myDate = rs.getString(4);
            myDate = myDate.substring(8, 10) + "-" + myDate.substring(5, 7) + "-" + myDate.substring(0, 4);
            json = json + "{"
                    + "\"id\": \"" + rs.getString(1) + "\","
                    + "\"title\": \"" + rs.getString(2) + "\","
                    + "\"detailMessage\": \"" + rs.getString(3) + "\","
                    + "\"whenAdd\": \"" + myDate + "\""
                    + "}";
            myTotal++;
        }
        json = json + "]";

        // Show it.
        myNewsInJSONFormat = json.toString();
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/json");
        externalContext.setResponseCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        externalContext.getResponseOutputWriter().write(myNewsInJSONFormat);
        facesContext.responseComplete();
        System.out.println("fina data is " + myNewsInJSONFormat);

        if (conn!=null) {
            conn.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        myNewsInJSONFormat = "";
    }
}
```

All was working perfectly, but the problem occurs WHEN I have new line and double quotes in text (especially at detailMessage).

Any workaround for new line and double quotes?

---

Sample JSON data is as below.. (with double quotes and new line)

```
[{"id": "6","title": "We can make iPhone app too now...","detailMessage": "Yes!!! You heard it "right"...

We can make iPhone app too with website....","whenAdd": "11-08-2013"}]
```

Comment: As I understand you get data from DB that contains new line and double quotes, right?

Comment: @MaximShoustin : yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) did the trick.

Below is the code I have

```
+ "\"detailMessage\": \"" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(rs.getString(3)) + "\","
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```